# Why std::bitset<5>{}[0] is not a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, std-bitset

std::bitset has constexpr constructor and constexpr operator[] so the following code compiles successfully:

```
#include <bitset>

typedef std::bitset<5> BitSet;

constexpr BitSet s1;
static_assert(!s1[0]);
```

buy why the following code does not?

```
static_assert(BitSet{}[0]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write `BitSet{}` a temporary object is created whose type is `BitSet`. But `std::bitset`'s [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) for non-const objects is *not* constexpr!

In your first example `s1` is implicitly `const`, so it uses the const `operator[]` which is `constexpr`.

Since you cannot `const` qualify a temporary directly (like `const Foo()` is not valid), you can always just add `const` to your alias:

```
using BitSet = const std::bitset<5>;
```

Comment: This is interesting. Shouldn't a prvalue constexpr?

Comment: @texasbruce Well no, since the prvalue cannot know that the surround context requires a constant expression.

Comment: That `using` thing with `const` is a useful trick. I'll have to remember that.